# CInvalidArgumentException when checking class in PreTranslateMessage

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++, mfc

The case: I'd like to make shortcuts with numpad so users can use my application fast. I implemented this in `PreTranslateMessage` and this worked.

But the case is that I have an Edit Control where the user should enter some number. So at the time the user has focus on a Edit Control (CEdit), the shortcuts should be **disabled**.

To cover this, I added

```
CWnd* pControl;
pControl = this->GetFocus();
if(!(pControl->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CEdit)))){
```

But now whenever my application dialog loses focus, it closes ([see video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEiBSP60kFQ)) and I get the following exeption:

[image: CinvalidArgException]

This is the full code:

```
// Handles keypresses for fast acces of functions
BOOL COpenFilesDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG *pMsg){
    CWnd* pControl;
    pControl = this->GetFocus();
    if(!(pControl->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CEdit)))){ //when this statement is commented the program doesn't crash
        if(pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            if((pMsg->wParam == 0x31 || pMsg->wParam == VK_NUMPAD1))
                someFunction();
            else if((pMsg->wParam == 0x33 || pMsg->wParam == VK_NUMPAD3)){
                someOtherFunction();
            }
        }
    }       

    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Now is my question: Why does my program crash when it is not in focus and how do I check if the focus is on a Edit Control in a proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CWnd::GetFocus` returns a pointer to the window that has the current focus, or NULL if there is no focus window.

```
pControl = this->GetFocus();
if ( pControl != NULL )
{
    if(!(pControl->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CEdit))))
    ...
}
```

Another way is to compare `pControl` value with pointer to `CEdit` class member (or members) of the dialog class. For example, if `CEdit m_edit` is edit box class member, test:

```
if ( pControl == (CWnd*)&m_edit )
{
    // focus is on m_edit control
}
```